# Form and SubForm Data pulling through Inner Join in MS-Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013, subform

While I am learning MS-Access, I got one doubt. I have two tables (S_School_Details, S_Personal_Information) looks like below

ID  Student Name  DOB             Class  Attendance
1    Ryan                12/06/2006      9th       96%
2   Paul                  11/01/2007       8th       92%

ID  Student Name    Fathers Name   Phone
1    Paul                    Wilson               62183478
2    Ryan                   Ben                   67194532
3    Will                      Morgan             78194567

I am trying to create a form with One Text Box with Student Name and SubForm and Search Button.
SubForm Should have details like... (Inner Join b/w two Tables). 
Student Name, Father Name, DOB, Class, Attendence, Phone Number

1. When I enter the student Name in form Text Box and click on Search Button should get the above mentioned details
2. If I entered any letter(Like R or S) in Form Text Box, should pull the details regarding that student
3. If I don’t give anything in Text box, It should pull all students details.

Without using Query table can we do this within Form only.

Comment: Your images do not show. Should include table samples as text, not images. A search form is common topic. Your question is too broad. Start with review of allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Here's that link again http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: This one I got it, Then how to Design it